# Troubles with PhpStorm web server debug validation

Tags: virtualbox, magento2, xdebug, remote-debugging, phpstorm-2018.2

In PhpStorm, I'm trying to debug code on remote server. Web server debug validation keeps telling me the specified url is not reachable (404).

My host is under windows

My server is on a VirtualBox VM (Debian 9)

I edit code with PhpStorm on a network drive `V:` pointing to my VM's `/var/www/` folder. This is not a VirtualBox shared folder (not supported for Debian 9).
So, when I work on `V:\myproject`, I'm actually working on `/var/www/myproject` on the VM through smb.

I followed a lot of tutorials, but never succeeded. Currently, I have the following configuration :

- PHP Cli remote interpreter, using a deployment configuration
- Said deployment configuration's connection type is SFTP (Connexion test is OK). Root path is `/var/www/myproject`. Webserver url is `https://my.project.local` (url was tested in my browser)
- Mapping local path : `V:\myproject`
- Mapping deployment path : `/`
- Mapping web path : `/pub` (this project is a Magento 2 application. Pub is the web root)

When I try validating web server debug, I select "Remote Web Server", the path to create validation script is `V:\myproject\pub`, deployment server is the previously described deployment configuration.

Validation fails, saying "Specified URL is not reachable, caused by: 'Request failed with status code 404'".

Has anyone already been through this specific setup ? (PhpStorm + remote debug on a VirtualBox VM + SFTP connection). Did you manage to make it work ?
Maybe I should try another way to make it work ? Help will be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but for anyone else having this problem that happens to be running Magento 2 on Nginx, look in **nginx.conf.sample**, or whatever ngxin.conf you're using.

Find the below block:

```
# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Modify it as such, allowing Nginx to serve the validation script:

```
# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check|_intellij_phpdebug_validator)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: This works. In case it is not working after doing these changes. Check what path you are using for "Path to create validation script": This should point to $MAGE_ROOT/pub in case of mac it should be /usr/local/var/www/pub. ( With the assumption that your magento is installed inside /usr/local/var/www). In the case of ubuntu it should be /var/www/html/pub.